# Scope of Crystal-structure and X-Ray-diffraction

Tags: discussion, tags

Today the [crystallography](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystallography) appeared in [Angular dependence of x-ray and neutron scattering factors](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32013/4945). I thought we do not need this tag as we already have [crystal-structure](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystal-structure) and I thought that we should rather extend the scope of this tag to include the procedure of obtaining such. I already [proposed it as a synonym to the tag](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tags/crystal-structure/synonyms).
When I was about to edit the tag wiki, I found out, that we already have the [x-ray-diffraction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray-diffraction), which would be appropriate to the question.
However, my initial thought is still persistent and I think, that synonymising would do no harm. If we keep the x-ray tag,  my proposed synonym would map to the wrong tag.
I wanted to retract my synonym proposal, but I did not find out how. I guess it has to be downvoted, to disappear or be removed by a mod. Since I made this mistake, I am apologising for the inconvenience.

I still would like to put it to a vote:
Should we merge the tags (and scopes) [crystallography](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystallography) and [x-ray-diffraction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray-diffraction) (and keep the latter as a synonym) or is there enough difference to keep them both alive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We need to keep [x-ray-diffraction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray-diffraction).

The most common application of x-ray diffraction methods is [crystallography](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystallography), however. However, there are other x-ray diffraction techniques used in the characterization of surfaces and materials, including:

- [Wide-angle x-ray scattering (WAXS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-angle_X-ray_scattering) - used to determine the degree of crystallinity of a (usually polymeric) sample
- [Small-angle x-ray scattering (SAXS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_X-ray_scattering) - used to investigate structural information in partially ordered macromolecules on the range of 5 to 25 nm
- [Energy-dispersive x-ray scattering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy-dispersive_X-ray_diffraction)

We need [x-ray-diffraction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray-diffraction) for these techniques, and the questions so tagged are about them (and not about crystallography):

- [Is it possible to construct a 3D molecular model using x-ray powder diffraction data?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20179/is-it-possible-to-construct-a-3d-molecular-model-using-x-ray-powder-diffraction)
- [Elastic scattering of x rays in 3D: the principle for XRD analysis](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19218/elastic-scattering-of-x-rays-in-3d-the-principle-for-xrd-analysis)
- [XRD-Shorter distance between planes than actual radius of atoms/or cell parameter](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18740/xrd-shorter-distance-between-planes-than-actual-radius-of-atoms-or-cell-paramete)

We should keep [x-ray-diffraction](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-ray-diffraction) and let [crystallography](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystallography) become a synonym for either the diffraction tag or [crystal-structure](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crystal-structure).

Comment: I think keeping x-ray-diffraction is a good idea.  I will wait for some more opinions about the other two.

Comment: Excellent post Ben. Since no one commented yet, I thought I could start. This may just be me, but I think perhaps crystallography is more directly related to x-ray diffraction than to crystal structure. I think there's a larger amount of crystal structure questions for which crystallography is not particularly relevant. For example, "Why does plutonium have so many polymorphs?", or "Why does diamond convert so slowly to graphite?", or "Why are some ionic salts good conductors as a solid?" are all related to crystal structure, but which aren't really related to the crystallography technique.

Comment: The last thing I wanted to do is push for a synonym (and get more entries in the tags). The whole question arose from my mistake of not checking properly and I think it is more than sufficiently answered. Thank you Ben. Now the last thing to do would be to burn the synonym proposal (two downvotes [read: score -2] should be enough).